# What materials allow $12\,\mathrm{\mu m}$ LWIR to pass?

Tags: optics, infrared-radiation, optical-materials

What commonly available materials will allow Infrared Radiation with wavelength of $12\,\mathrm{\mu m}$ to pass through?

Commonly available is something that can be obtained easily for manufacturing.

Thanks,

Comment: Glass will pass $12\mu m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Germanium, Zinc Selenide, Barium Fluoride, Sodium Chloride, and Potassium Bromide all pass 12 $\mu$m radiation, and are easily available.  Whether or not they are suitable for your application is another question entirely.   I think most can be machined by diamond turning, but some, the last two in particular, will become cloudy in humid conditions.

Comment: My understanding is there is no relatively inexpensive, printable sheet-like material that is opaque to visible light but transparent to LWIR that can be used as the opposite of glass

Comment: What do you mean by "sheet-like"?   What are you trying to make?